# Bootstrap yamm hover on dropdown set another to to display block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using yamm.css to make a super nav sub menu show when i hover using the following code:

```
 ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
 }
```

The above works fine, however i have another div which in the css is set to display:none; This div is called

What i want to happen is when i hover over the navigation menu the sub menu will display and then set that bgCover to display:block; when hovered.

Is it possible to do with CSS? I have tried the below but doesn't work:

```
 ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu .bgCover,
 ul.nav li.dropdown:hover .bgCover {
    display: block;    
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to achieve this:

Load jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When hovering over 'dropdown' show 'bgCover'.

```
<script>
    $( "ul.nav li.dropdown" ).hover(
        function() {
        $(".bgCover").show();
    });
</script>
```